# How do I set NODE_ENV and DEBUG?

Tags: node.js

`NODE_ENV=dev node server.js`

That is the `start` script in my package.json file. So, I start the app with `npm start`

I want to use the `debug` module, but I am unsure how to set multiple environment variables when starting the app as I am above.

How would I add `DEBUG=*` to the start script above?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=* node server.js
```

and in your package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "yourApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=* node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {

    ...

  }
}
```

Comment: How would I add DEBUG in addition to NODE_ENV?

Comment: it doen't works. i am getting 'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is already given but I will add some more detail as I was looking for debugging only request.

To work with ***express***

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=express:* node server.js
```

or

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=myapp node server.js
```

and as mention by @agconti

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=* node server.js
```

To debug ***particular*** namespace

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=request:* node server.js
```

You can also ***exclude*** particular namespace

By prefixing them with a `"-"` character. For example, `DEBUG=*,-request:*` would include all debuggers except those starting with `"request:".`

Comment: is there a reference document for the behavior / format of the DEBUG variable?

Comment: @Cheeso, this feature is most often implemented by https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug library and in its docs you can find more info on use of DEBUG variable, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

You set multiple env vars the same way you set 1

```
NODE_ENV=dev DEBUG=* node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your shell and export the variable. This will only work for the current session, so if you want it to be forever, then find you `.bashrc` file and append this line to it.

`export NODE_ENV=dev`

Comment: this isn't always desirable.  he can set `DEBUG` inline exactly the same way as `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I would like to define DEBUG as well as NODE_ENV in a script definition of package.json. My problem is with the format to define multiple vars inline like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see some logging, there is also `NODE_DEBUG` for each module:

```
NODE_DEBUG=module1,module2 node yourScript.js
```

To enable a full logging, a wildcard can be used:

```
NODE_DEBUG=* node yourScript.js
```